# json_encode to pass array to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, moodle

I am trying to pass an array obtained from a web-service to View in codeigniter. I am unable to pass Array from json_encode() method. When I print the array it displays all the records from the database but whenever I try to pass it by encoding JSON it only returns a single value. Why?

Here is my Code:

```
<?php 
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../config.php');
$result = $DB->get_records_sql('SELECT er.*,ed.* FROM mdl_scorm ed INNER JOIN mdl_course_modules er ON ed.id = er.instance WHERE er.course="2" AND er.module="18"');
$out = array_values($result);
$jsondata = json_encode($out);
//echo'<pre>';
//print_r($jsondata);
echo $jsondata;
```

Comment: can you give your $result.

Comment: What value you are getting in `$result`?

Comment: Hi Vaibhav and Sougata, Instead of all records from both table below is the result for id and name field.

Comment: Array
(
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Test
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Test_2
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => Test_333
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => Test_4
        )

)

Comment: Try to get mysql result into array format ...as currently it is returning stdObject it might be possible array_values not returin value...

or you can try to iterate through result and store it into array and then json_encode it

Comment: What value you are getting in $out ?